# ms access vba, set number limit, enter number, it fills the limit(s) on different report page

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm new to databases and MS-Access, this might be simple but I can't find anything related to this.

Lets say you have a set number limit at 20. And in a Forms textbox you enter 75.

It should make report pages, 3 pages with number 20 written somewhere and 1 page with a written number 15.

In the end combining a number 75 across the pages, with max on 1 page being 20.

Please help.

Comment: This sounds like you want to perform paging. You do this in the client program that calls your database, not the database itself. Or are you asking how you can select a certain range from your data?

Comment: I don't think it is paging. But no, I don't want to select the range for the data. Just the literal number that you enter, it gets divided between report pages, depending on the limit you have set for that number. So if the limit is 20, 1st time you enter 40, you get 2 pages on each written 20 and the 2nd time you enter 55, you get 3 report pages, 2 with 20 and 1 with 15 written on it. Nothing fancy, just the number divide. Maybe it is not possible, the way I imagined.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem very clear; what you're describing sounds like paging.

Comment: What data is your report based on? (Or isn't there any data besides the numbers?)

Comment: Ok forget its an MS-Access, imagine a video game, where if you get 100 points you get an extra Life and then it starts counting from beginning. Same here, I want a limit, be it 100 or 20 or 5000 and instead of getting the points, one by one, you just enter it, so if the point limit is 100 and I enter 200, I get 2 Lifes or 2 report pages.

Comment: @Andre well I have multiple tables with data, names and etc. 1 query where all the tables are combined. And multiple forms and reports depending on how I choose the data. But this specific thing isn't dependent on data, just a number you enter. It is more of a looks thing, so the person doesn't have to write the number on a printed report with a pencil, instead he can enter the sum of the number in a Form and cause of the limits, it gets split between Reports. The data on all reports is the same, except that one number changes. Now it is more complicated I think.

Comment: Uh, what, now it's different reports? I think you lost me.

Comment: The other Reports don't matter.

Comment: It should be something like this.

|Limit: 20|| Enter nr: 35 | ------> | nr: 20   | ------> | nr: 15  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is really an access question, but simple logic.  Here's some pseudocode for ya:

```
textboxnum = 75
maxnum = 20

while textboxnum > maxnum
   print maxnum
   textboxnum =  textboxnum - maxnum
loop

print textboxnum
```

Comment: and if you're doing this in Access, then instead of Print you're just going to assign the above to a table, and on the report you'll put this field in the header so that each new value appears on a separate page.

Comment: After some tinkering its working! Thank you very much, I really just needed to add your logic code in my code and make it fit and everything works as I wanted. Thank you very very much!